# Expected number of passengers for the flight

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-coefficients, mathematica

One of the interview questions that I was asked was :

> The small commuter plane has 30 seats. The probability that any
>   particular passenger will not show up for a flight is 0.1, independent
>   of other passengers.
>
> Design a function to get largest m value such that expectedshow[m] =
>   expected number of passengers showing up if 30 + m tickets are sold
>   for a flight and expectedshow[m] ≤ 30.

I could not think of a way to approach this question. Can somebody explain it ?

Comment: First $(30+m)\cdot0.9\leq30\implies0.9m\leq3\implies{m}\leq3.3$. Then $[m\in\mathbb{N}]\wedge[m\leq3.3]\implies\max(m)=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ tickets are sold, then the expected number of passengers that will show is $0.9n$, by linearity of expectation.

However, in this problem the variable is not $n$, but $m$, where $n=30+m$.  Hence the number of expected passengers that will show is $0.9(30+m)$.  Now consider those values of $m$ that make this at most 30; choose the largest.  You should get $$\frac{30}{0.9}-30=3.\overline{3}$$
Most likely the interviewer is looking for the floor of this, namely $m=3$.